Complex Integral and Residue involving multiple Branch Points inside the contour
I encountered the integral:
$$\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z) \ dz}{\sqrt{(z-a)(z-b)}}  \ \ \ \ \text{with} \ \ \ |a|,|b| < 1$$
So that the branch points are inside the contour. I am not adding the explicit form of $f(z)$ for this context but want to learn how these things are tackled.
I want to find the residues of $ \frac{f(z)}{\sqrt{(z-a)(z-b)}}$ at both $a$ and $b$. There's no possibility of deforming the contour since it is fixed for the problem under consideration, which is simply the unit circle around origin of the complex plane.
How do I proceed? I am not expecting any full answer but either a clear direction or a good resource will be highly appreciated.

The strategy will depend a lot on $f$. I'll assume for simplicity that $f$ is meromorphic. Technically your integrand is ill defined since the square root is double valued: you need to specify the branch. I'll further assume that you chose a branch cut within the circle linking $a,b$ so that the contour stays in the same branch.
For this kind of integral, the usual approach is to instead consider the residues outside the circle. Visually, it amounts to shrinking the circle to a point by making it pass through infinity instead of the origin, taking into account any simple pole you cross along the way. You'll need to be careful not to forget the contribution of $\sqrt{(z-a)(z-b)}$ at infinity.
I'll illustrate this by the following example:
$$
I = \oint_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{z^2-1}}
$$
where I'll choose the branch cut to be the segment $[-1,1]$, and the usual branch so that $\sqrt{z^2-1}\sim z$ at infinity (not $-z$). The integrand is analytic in the complement of the disk of radius $2$. At infinity, it has a simple pole, which you can see by the usual change of variable: $w = 1/z$ and the Laurent expansion:
$$
\frac{dz}{\sqrt{z^2-1}} = -\frac{dw}{w^2\sqrt{1/w^2-1}} \\
-\frac1{w\sqrt{1-w^2}} = -\frac1w +...
$$
Therefore, there is only a simple pole at infinity with residue $-1$, so (beware of the contour orientation: anticlockwise around the circle, so it is clockwise for infinity which gives an extra minus sign):
$$
I = 2\pi i
$$
This is consistent with another method useful method that consists of shrinking the contour so as to snugly encircle the branch cut (a double Hankel contour):
$$
I = 2i\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = 2\pi i
$$
Hope this helps.

thank you for the clarified edit.

Kindly take a look at the link, where the full problem and the still-present difficulties are put together. Your comments may help more in that context since the previous method will fail in the case I am after.
